# Clean install of OS X, nothing happening at OS X Utilities

Tags: macos, install, disk-utility

I'm trying to do a clean install OS X Mavericks. Previously I had Lion and thought it was time to get something a little more recent. I don't think my 2010 MacBook Pro could handle Sierra so I had a friend send over the Mavericks install file

I made a bootable USB and then erased my hard drive through Disk Utility, I then created 2 partitions.

Now, after booting up my Mac, I seem to be stuck on the 'OS X Utilities' bit. I click 'continue' after selecting to install OS X, and nothing happens.

Tried restarting but to no avail.

Might my bootable install be corrupted?

Comment: How did you create your bootable OS X installer thumb drive? Do you still have the Mavericks installer?

Comment: Discovering your other q&a it seems likely that the OS X installer app is hosed, tampered etc. Countercheck the InstallESD.dmg with this sha list: [Apple Installer Checksums](https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums)

Comment: thanks for the responses, I'm just in the process of downloading / trying a different Mavericks install file so will see how I get on with that!